# Python error: No module named 'matplotlib.pylot' even though it is installed

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to run a .py script on my Manjaro box and I keep getting the following error:

```
[keithm@home2 python]$ python3 gspppff.py
['/home/keithm/bin/python', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/keithm/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gspppff.py", line 7, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pylot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pylot'
```

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import datetime as dt

import sys
print(sys.path)
import matplotlib.pylot as plt

from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

# graph style
style.use('ggplot')

start = dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()

# dataframe
df = web.DataReader("TSLA", 'morningstar', start, end)

print(df.head())
```

I included `print(sys.path)` to see where python was looking for the mods and I made sure matlablib was installed in both locally: `/home/keithm/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` and in `/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, but still no change.

Comment: The module name is `matplotlib.pyplot` - you have `pylot`.

Answer (score 2):

The package name is "pyplot", not "pylot". Here is the corrected code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 0):

It's spelled "pyplot", not "pylot".

Answer (score 0):

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

try "pyplot" you have incorrect spelling